# How many commercial or ATP pilots have lost their medical yearly from 2015 to 2022?

Tags: commercial-aviation, medical, commercial-operations, airline-pilot

I wold like to know how many pilots have lost their medical that prohibits flying on a commercial or ATP, year to year from 2015 to 2022.

Comment: I doubt this is public information...

Comment: You need to write the FAA to see if that statistical data is publicly available.